# Need to covert form value to object after appending to formdata

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Trying to submit a form using formgroup, Initially the for value was an object but after appending to formdata the value becomes string so that i cannot parse the data in query.

```
users form value after submit:-

[
   {
    "id": "",
    "employee": "6166d234379ec5e4c9b3fe3",
    "position": "Manager",
    "users": [
        "715ea5df332403e4215324234",
        "815ea33534534333e42153432"
    ],
  }
]

 Object.keys(this.Form.controls).forEach(key => {
      if(key == 'users'){
     console.log(typeof(this.Form.get(key).value)) //type is object
     formData.append(key,this.Form.get(key).value);
    }
  });

 formData.forEach((value,key) => {
       console.log(key+" "+typeof(value)) // type of value  becomes  string
 });

 //trying covert it to object
 formData.forEach((value,key) => {
  if(key == 'users'){
       formData.set(key,JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)));
       //formData.set(key,JSON.parse(value)); //return error SyntaxError: Unexpected token o 
    in JSON at position
       console.log(key+" "+typeof(value)) // still string
   }
});

 need to submit the formdata with users as object
```

Comment: You need to provide additional context to your question - there is no information about what this.Form is, nor the actual initialization of formData.

Comment: @jdpnielsen Thank you for the reply,sure, i just need to convert that formdata with key "users"
to object, but after appending to formdata it becomes string.. is there any way to make it as object as my tries are all failed!

Comment: Please check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormData can only be simple key/value pairs of strings. If you must use a FormData object, you can experiment with appending your values as json-encoded strings:

```js
formData.append(key, JSON.stringify(this.Form.get(key).value));
```

This will allow you to parse the values later:

```js
 formData.forEach((value, key) => {
       console.log(key, JSON.parse(value));
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! actually my intension is to convert the value this.Form.get(key).value of users to an object rather  than string may i know is it possible anyway? i can use this value in backend query only when the value is object string not possible! Thanks! I need to pass the entire object in http request!